# How to get current process pid?

Tags: macos, pid

I need to get the pid of current processs on Mac OS?
I find that GetCurrentProcess function is deprecated.
So is there any other methods?

Answer (score 3):

By using [`getpid()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/getpid.2.html), just like any other UNIX system. (The documentation I've linked to is related to iOS, but the system call works identically on macOS.)

The GetCurrentProcess call was part of the Carbon API, which was made available for porting applications from Mac OS 9. It's no longer available in current versions of macOS.

Comment: Do you have an updated link to getpid()? The one above doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @DavidStansby Hmm, seems like Apple's removed the macOS manual pages from their developer site. I've found the equivalent documentation for iOS.

Comment: Are you sure the pid is the same as the "process serial number" (PSN) that GetCurrentProcess returns?

Answer (score 0):

You can install pidof with Homebrew:

```
`
brew install pidof
pidof <process_name>
  `
```